# uglifyjs javascript inside php files

Tags: javascript, php, minify, uglifyjs

My project has a lot of JS code inside PHP files.  I want to minify the JS code in these files and I like the [uglifyjs2 program](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2).  Is it possible for that (or any) JS minifier to act on JS code *INSIDE* a php file?

Someone is going to suggest removing all JS code from the PHP files and placing it in .js files - but that isn't always practical.

Keep in mind that I do **NOT** wish to minify the JS on the fly (acting on the output of the PHP interpreter).  I am delivering PHP code to customers containing JS, and I wish to minify the JS inside the PHP files that I am delivering.

Comment: https://github.com/makesites/uglifyjs-php  ... This? It literally seems to be the solution for your case :P

Comment: @briosheje Totally off-topic. He's not looking for a PHP API for Uglify.

Comment: @meagar: Why not? I mean, the goal is minifying JS in PHP, no?

Comment: @briosheje He's trying to minify JavaScript that is *inside* his PHP files. A PHP API for minifying external scripts isn't useful here.

Comment: I used gzip to minify encapsulated js and unpack in memory when code is needed. Not sure this is what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for does not exist.

The only real reason to have inline JavaScript inside your PHP files is because you need to interpolate PHP and JavaScript in order to dynamically generate some or all of the script. You cannot reliably minify such JavaScript *before* the PHP is actually processed, so you'd be looking at minifying it *after* the PHP is run, on every request. There *should* be very little value to this, as the vast bulk of your JavaScript should not be written inside your PHP files.

Comment: Javascript cannot interactact with or depend on PHP code...so I don't agree that you cannot minify the JS until after the PHP has been processed.  There are many reasons to put JS code directly in the PHP (eg: minimize load times for multiple JS segments inside a PHP file)

Comment: @GenerationDSystems: although it's usually not good practice, some users echo variables to JavaScript, doing things like `var a = "<?php echo 'Hello world!' ?>";` or something along those lines.

Comment: @GenerationDSystems That is true, but PHP can absolutely interact with the static JavaScript it's generating.  PHP-generated JavaScript is going to break minification often enough that you just shouldn't do it. Minification usually involves changing identifiers, and it cannot possibly hope to work if you use those identifiers anywhere in PHP.

Answer (score -1):

Whatever the php script generates as output is sent to the browser. If you sent the "actual" output of the script instead of the output stream to another application and fetch and redirect *that* output - yes, you can do just anything.
Another question is how feasible and reasonable that approach is. uglifyjs2 is a node.js appliation, and therefore this step would require some kind of interprocess communication, i.e. extra-complexity and extra time/memory/points-of-failure and all that good stuff.
Maybe it's worth the effort, maybe not. Maybe something like https://github.com/tedious/JShrink will suffice...

Comment: I don't wish to minify on the fly, so acting on the output of the PHP interpreter isn't applicable.  I wish to minify the JS code inside PHP files (which are delivered to customers to run in their own environment)